# Is there a way to send a running terminal command to the background AND change the output to pipe to a log file?

Tags: bash, unix, zsh

Sometimes when I run a log running terminal command, I'd like to send it to the background and start doing something else in the same shell. I can do this with `Ctrl+Z` and `bg`.

However, the annoying effect this has is that it keeps showing output of the above command intermittently. Instead, when I move the process to the background, I'd also like to change where the output goes as well.

Importantly, I'm asking how to do this for an already-running command - I know that do this from scratch I could do something like `command arg1 arg2 &> ~/logs/output.log &`.

Comment: `foo &> bar` sets up FD 1 and FD 2 to point to `bar` _before_ it starts `foo`. Changing where file descriptors point after-the-fact, when a program wasn't started in a way explicitly intended to support it, involves nasty, nasty hacks.

Comment: (and by that, I mean "connect with a debugger and run code within the target process" level of nasty hacks; this isn't something bash or zsh has built-in)

Comment: Anyhow -- if you're asking how to do this _as a user_, the question is arguably off-topic here, and would be better at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If you're the person _developing_ the script, then you've got more choices; you can, for example, set up a signal handler for an otherwise-unused signal like SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2, and trigger a redirection after-the-fact from a trap.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Reptyr for this in the past.

It does have its limitations (especially with GUIs / Curses) but has worked well for me.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/reptyr

You can either start a Screen session and use reptyr to grab your running process into the screen session. Or start a new bash session which is outputting to a file and then grab the running process with reptyr.